# Server side function is not working using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/jsonrep",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
  }
  function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
  }
</script> 

<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" 
       onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
```

and code file code is

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public string jsonrep()
{
    GetOrders();
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(list);

    return json.ToString();
}

public List<DataProp> GetOrders()
{
    DataProp o = new DataProp();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        o.Earning = 20000 * i;
        o.Number = 8 * i;
        list.Add(o);
    }

    return list;
}
```

I want to call a server side function using jQuery which return a json object but function not working - what am I doing wrong? If I call function on page load it work fine is that function return a json data. Please help

Comment: You will have problems with this if you are using Master pages. I have not been able to successfully call a WebMethod from a CodeBehind page when using Master pages. I ended up creating a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `static` reference in this line :

```
public string jsonrep()
```

Change it to

```
public static string jsonrep()
```

[Look at this link if you want to know why your method needs to be static](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/). From the link :

> A static method is simply one that is disassociated from any instance of its containing class. The more common alternative is an instance method, which is a method whose result is dependent on the state of a particular instance of the class it belongs to. In a sense, static methods are **stateless** methods.

So, JS understands only static methods because only they can be instantiated without a class reference.

If you want to use something, non-static, I suggest you use an `asmx` service/ an `ashx` handler.